# htaccess: redirect to https://subdomain.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I want to redirect my website to `https://subdomain.domain.com` in my .htaccess file.

Redirects:

http://subdomain.domain.com             **=> https://subdomain.domain.com**

http://www.subdomain.domain.com         **=> https://subdomain.domain.com**

https://www.subdomain.domain.com        **=> https://subdomain.domain.com**

https://subdomain.domain.com            **=> no redirects**

Answer (score 0):

This should do it…

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

First rule redirect all www to https://subdomain.domain.com, second all http to https://subdomain.domain.com

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```